# What's the name of this geometric mathematical modeling problem?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, mathematical-modeling

There is a right angle corner with width 1 in both directions. One wants to find the largest area shape which can pass through this corner.
I know that this is a famous problem, but what is it called?

Comment: Manhole problem ?

Comment: @Hachino Actually not... The right ans is from Ian Farrell.

Comment: A 13-minute-long video featuring Dan Romik on the [Moving Sofa Problem](https://youtu.be/rXfKWIZQIo4).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Moving sofa problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_sofa_problem), I believe.

Comment: From personal experience ... sofas move in 3 dimensions.  Many years ago another mathematician was helping me move.  We had to carry a sofa up a flight of stairs, then turn a corner at the top.  It didn't fit.  But he says, "Just rotate it this way..." and it did fit.  I still don't know what he did.

Comment: An instance where transseries wouldn't have helped, I suppose.  Gerhard "Guess Geometry's Good For Something" Paseman, 2015.04.01

Answer (score 9):

A supplement to Ian's answer: Here is the largest-area sofa known,
due to Gerver:

---

[image: GerverSofa]

---

> Gerver, Joseph L. (1992). "On Moving a Sofa Around a Corner". *Geometriae Dedicata* 42 (3): 267–283. ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02414066).)

**Added** (triggered by @GeraldEdgar's remark).
The computational complexity of algorithms grows
exponentially in the dimension, about $n^5$ for
polyhedral objects with $n$ vertices moving in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
Here is an algorithm moving an $n{=}4500$-triangle piano
through a challenging apartment requiring several tricky maneuvers:

---

[image: Piano]

---

> Kuffner, James J., and Steven M. LaValle. "RRT-connect: An efficient approach to single-query path planning." *Robotics and Automation*, 2000. Proceedings. ICRA'00. IEEE International Conference on. Vol. 2. IEEE, 2000. 
>   ([IEEE link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=844730&abstractAccess=no&userType=inst).)

Not surprisingly, the problem is also called *The Piano Mover's Problem*.

Comment: Manifestly, to find the largest solid that would pass through a unit cube corner, the solution would be obtained by endowing the largest-area sofa known with height 1.

Comment: New (Jun 2017) paper by Yoav Kallus and Dan Romik: "Improved upper bounds in the moving sofa problem," [arXiv abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06630).